# Login Form Using sqlDataReader HasRow always false

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

I have always used `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet` to make Login Forms. The logic used to be like after satisfying my query, if there is more than 0 record then the login is successful.

But now I am trying the same thing using `SqlDataReader`. But even the query return one row in the SQL Server Management Studio, `SqlDataReader` detects no row and skips the code block. Where am I doing this wrong?

```
public static bool Login(string username, string password)
{
        string CString = DatabaseHelper.CString;
        string CText = "select id from tblUser where username='@username' and password='@password'";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CText, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                        UserSession usr = new UserSession();
                        usr.userId = rdr["id"].ToString();
                        usr.username = username;
                        usr.isLoggedIn = true;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] = usr;
                        return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the parameters placeholders between single quotes.
In this way they are treated as literal strings and, of course,  you don't have any row where the `Username` column contains the literal string "@username" and the same for "@password"

```
 string CText = @"select id 
                  from tblUser 
                  where username=@username 
                        and password=@password";
```

Comment: Oh I am so embarrassed to make such mistake. Thanks. It worked! :)